# Notepad++ find next same word

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++,when I select a word, all the same word is highlighted, but it's sometimes hard to find next word if the text is too long. I can use the Ctrl+F3 to search for the next match word, However the other words containing the desired word is also found as the result. For example:

```
scroll:true
scrollSpeed:10
/********foo  **********/
if(scroll){/***** dsferaga#%$R&*^%*&^*********/}
```

when I select "scroll","scroll" in the first and forth line will be highlighted,but not the "scrollSpeed".when I want to jump to the next "scroll",I use Ctrl+F3 and It went to the "scrollSpeed" in the second line.

Is there an proper shortcut for that?

Answer (score 6):

Open the Find dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and tick the "Match whole word only" checkbox. The next time you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> that option will still be active.

Tested on version 5.8.1.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set **whole word only** option

Comment: no,using serch panel is too inconvenient，I want an shortcut to find the next word match the current word

Answer (score 1):

If it is to find your repeated word in a large text use the `SmartHighlighter Plugin` and it will show the word position near scroll bar.

For installation details. Check below link.
[Rockscroll like plugin for notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380636/rockscroll-like-plugin-for-notepad/55819529#55819529)