# Rockscroll like plugin for notepad++?

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++

Is there a plugin like Rockscoll for VisualStudio for notepad++ ?
Atleast anything close to it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's built-in:

`View -> Document Map`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks !! But there is no highlighting in the map if I select a word !! In rockscroll, it will highlight all repeats of the word in the view. Is there a way to enable it ? Is it supported?

Comment: mmmnnope don't think so - at least not with the document map

Comment: have a look through http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

Comment: If you want highlighting of the selected word, try "SmartHighlighter" which is one bit of the jN Plugin suite https://code.google.com/p/jn-npp-plugin/
The highlighting is only shown in the normal toolbar, not in the Document map, but it's still good!
A warning, if you disable some of the other "includes" in jN by moving them into the disabled folder, in order to just have "SmartHighlighting", *don't* disable MenuCmds.js otherwise "SmartHighlighting" won't work!

Comment: About SmartHighlighter:  https://superuser.com/questions/216088/can-notepad-mark-scrollbar-with-visual-indicators-of-search-results

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SmartHighlighter`. This answer is from the https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/3116

**Steps**

1. Download the latest release of the plugin from https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/releases

   - If notepad++ folder is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` download the file with `_x86.zip` suffix
   - If notepad++ folder is in `C:\Program Files\Notepad++` download the file with `_x64.zip` suffix

     > From here on if your installation is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++` just replace `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`. Procedure is same in both cases.
2. Create a new folder at `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins` with name `jN`
3. Extract the contents of the downloaded zip file to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\jN`
4. Optionally, jN plugin includes other components also. So to disable all components of the jN plugin except for Smart Highlighter, Go to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\jN\includes` and keep only below files:

   ```
   Dialog.js  
   MenuCmds.js  
   SmartHighlighter.js
   ```

   and move the rest of the .js files to `disabled` folder.
   `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\jN\includes\disabled`
5. Now close and reopen your Notepad++.
6. Now try selecting a repeated word and check the bar next to your scrollbar. That's it.

Comment: Thanks, it's working as expected. But how do I make it a thick line in scrollbar?

Comment: @Rohit Create a New issue in https://github.com/sieukrem/jn-npp-plugin/issues and ask there. Maybe the plugin developers will guide you.